# How to programatically discover unregistered web services deployed in Weblogic?

Tags: web-services, weblogic, discovery, wlst

There are a number of teams who have deployed applications to a shared Weblogic application server.  There has been some effort to maintain a registry but it hasn't been kept up to date.  How can you programmatically discover all the web services deployed to a server and retrieve their WSDL?

Interactively, from the console, you can navigate to Deployments->Monitoring->Web Services and then enable the URI field, which is hidden by default.  From this list, I can construct the WSDL: [host]:[port][URI]?WSDL

I think it is doable using JMX and have been playing with the WLST shell.  The "listApplications()" command gives a list of the application names, but its not clear how to get more information.